# About Facebook AppID and URL

Tags: storage, facebook-authentication

Due to every AppID seems need a correspond URL, that means, every our device needs to apply one AppID with its URL. This is not suitable and not OK for our device goes into mass production due to we don't know the url of the end user. So, does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

*

> Facebook doesn't allow to create appid now, am having below error.
>
> *You can no longer create apps because our systems indicated that your account may not be authentic. Facebook requires users to provide their
>   real first and last names, and fake accounts are a violation of our
>   Statement of Rights and Responsibilities (SRR 4.1), even when used to
>   host or test apps. Also note that maintaining multiple accounts, even
>   if they are authentic, is also prohibited. If you would like to create
>   a test user to test app functionality, you can do so here:
>   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/.*

  *